# magento ajax layered navigation data came from cache

Tags: cache, layered-navigation, ajax, varnish, redis

I have ajax layered navigation extension and varnish magento extension. they seem to have category products came from cache. Ajax layered navigation ajax loader is triggered when I select a pagination from toolbar. i had tried disabled the varnish module then after the data is came from cache. Any guidance on this?